# Add list of files in a folder

Tags: java

I am developing an application and I need to save all my files in a directory for each user. Half I've writen, but I'm unclear how to add files to the directory.

```
public boolean addFiles(String name,List<File> files){
    String path = "D:\\Server Repository\\UsersFiles\\";
    File folder = new File(path + name);

    if(!folder.exists()) 
          folder.mkdirs();

    for(File file:files){
        //my code 
        //if all ended with success return true
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want 3rd party libs like FileUtils, and just want a simple code to copy the files, you can do it like this:

```
public boolean addFiles(String name, List<File> files) {
    String path = "D:\\Server Repository\\UsersFiles\\";
    File folder = new File(path + name);

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        for (File file : files) {
            FileInputStream fisOrigin;
            FileOutputStream fosDestiny;
            //channels  
            FileChannel fcOrigin;
            FileChannel fcDestiny;

            fisOrigin = new FileInputStream(file);
            fosDestiny = new FileOutputStream(new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + file.getName()));

            fcOrigin = fisOrigin.getChannel();
            fcDestiny = fosDestiny.getChannel();
            //Copy the file
            fcOrigin.transferTo(0, fcOrigin.size(), fcDestiny);

            fisOrigin.close();
            fosDestiny.close();
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro, you help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons-IO API supports this. Have a look at the [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is

```
copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile, boolean preserveFileDate)
```

from [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

In your case;

```
 for(File file:files){
        String dest = folder + file.name();
        copyFile(file, dest, true);
    }
```